# AngularJS - angular-ui-tinymce - Text entered in tinymce element on a form does not make the form $dirty

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am not sure if anyone can help with this but our team are using the following code:

```
<form novalidate name="itemForm">

    <input 
     class="input-medium" 
     data-ng-disabled="action=='delete'" 
     data-ng-model="formData.title" id="Text2" required type="text">

    <textarea 
     data-ui-tinymce 
     data-ng-model="tab.text"></textarea>

    <button type="submit"
     data-ng-click="submitItem(formData)"
     data-ng-disabled="itemForm.$pristine"> {{modal.submitText}} </button>

</form>
```

When typing into the input box at the start of the code the submit button becomes enabled. However when typing into the tinymce window the button does not become enabled. Everything else works okay but just not the form's dirty / pristine state. I think what is needed is for the tinymce directive to change the value of pristine but I am not sure how to code this.

Would appreciate some advice on how to handle this problem. I did raise this is a question on the GitHub and the response was that it was not handled but that we could submit a pull request for it.
Unfortunately we're very much at the beginning of our learning curve and not sure how to do this. Has anyone else come across this problem when using the tinymce inside a form in AngularJS?

Comment: $pristine works in [this example](http://embed.plnkr.co/CnNoRB6u22in8R8PwWGG/preview).  May be something else causing the $pristine state to not change?

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to check it out. I will have a good look at this tomorrow and try and work out what's happening.

Comment: No problem.  Good opportunity for me to check out tinymce - I'd never used it before.  Very cool.